# When I select checkbox in a row. It selects all the checkbox available in angular 7 table?

Tags: angular, checkbox

When i select a checkbox in a row, It selects all the checkbox available in table. Here is the code i have used for populating checkbox in a table

```html
<thead>
<tr>
   <th scope="col">Attach</th>
   <th scope="col">Link</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let list of complianceReports.selectedData;let i = index">
        <td>
            <input id=" {{ i+1 }} " type="checkbox" name="attach[$index]" class="setup-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="complianceReports.attach[$index]">{{i+1}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="complianceReports.link[$index]" type="checkbox" name="link[$index]" class="setup-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="complianceReports.link[$index]">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How to select checkbox in a row as per need in angular 7

Comment: its ng Model problem.. may be your ngModel value is same for all checkbox. its should be unique

Comment: are you sure about your code? you have items (list) of an array (selectedData) and then you ignore both (list and selectedData) and access another two arrays (attach and links)? shouldn't it be for each item: "list.attach" and "list.link"?

Comment: @antseq Yes, My code is correct. I am using two different array for binding checkbox

Comment: can you paste sample data for arrays being used?

Comment: I think is the main problem with the $index becuase it 's not changing all input bound to the same refrence 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `i (index)` instand of `$index` when you bind to **ngModel**

```
<tr *ngFor="let list of complianceReports.selectedData;let i = index">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="setup-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="complianceReports.attach[i]">{{i+1}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  type="checkbox" class="setup-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="complianceReports.link[i]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have troubles with the use of variables in tag property with Angular. Your problem comes from the `name` of your inputs. They are all the same: the string `attach[$index]`. You should have use brackets arount `name`to tell Angular that it needs to interpolate its value.

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let list of complianceReports.selectedData;let i = index">
        <td>
            <input [id]="i+1" type="checkbox" [name]="attach[$index]" class="setup-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="complianceReports.attach[$index]">{{i+1}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input [id]="complianceReports.link[$index]" type="checkbox" [name]="link[$index]" class="setup-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="complianceReports.link[$index]">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: When i Use name as [name], I am getting the following issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: Because your object `attach[$index]` must be a complex object. It must be a unique string or number.